# Google Analytics and BigQuery link issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting an error while linking Bigquery to Google analytics" ***We encountered a permission error for the selected BigQuery project. Please ensure that the service account has edit permissions on the project and try again. See the linking instructions for more information.***

I want to know how to set up service account on  cloud console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is usually related to two types of permissions, one is the Service Account that you use to access BigQuery and the other is the email address you use to login to Google Analytics.

1. Service Account

- In order to create a new service account, you should follow the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#before-you-begin). So, in ***IAM & Admin > Service Accounts > Create Service account***. Then,

> - **1:** *give the service account details*,
> - **2:** *Grant this service account access to project(select the roles)* and
> - **3:** *Grant users access to this service account(add users)*

- In your case make sure that, you have to add this service account `analytics-processing-dev@system.gserviceaccount.com` to your project. In order to don so, you have to navigate to ***IAM & Admin > IAM***. Then, click in the top right corner ***ADD***, copy and pate the service account and **Select a role**: *Project > Editor*, [link for the documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089#step2).

2. Permissions in Google Analytics

- The email you use to login with Google Analytics must to have *OWNER* access to the BigQuery Project and ***[Edit](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495)***  permission for the Analytics property that includes the view you want to link, [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089#step3).

Therefore, after performing these actions, you will be able to link BigQuery with Google Analytics.

*Attention: In addition, I must mention that you first have to ensure you enabled Billing for your project, [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089#step2).*